# Compare the two data - MySQL & PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I want to compare the two data and if the data are identical with each other, write the name of the data

How can a better query?

For Example:

```
 ExampleTable1 * ID    = 5  --
                              | (5=5) ---> "Hello This Five" (vtname)
 ExampleTable2 * BEID  = 5  --
```

SQL:

```
$sql1 = "SELECT * FROM ExampleTable1 WHERE paid= ".$paidsi;
$result1 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql1); 
if (mysqli_num_rows($result1) > 0) { 
    while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1)) {
        $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM ExampleTable2";
        $result2 = $conn->query($sql2); 
            if ($result2->num_rows > 0) { 
                while($row2 = $result2->fetch_assoc()) {
                    if ($row2["id"] == $row1["beid"]) {
                        echo $row2["vtname"]; 
                    } else {
                    echo "";
                    } 
                }
            } else {
                echo "0 results";
            }   
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use [left join](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp)

```
$sql1 = "SELECT * FROM ExampleTable1 E1
            LEFT JOIN ExampleTable2 E2 ON E1.id = E2.beid";

$result1 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql1); 

if (mysqli_num_rows($result1) > 0) { 
    while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1)) {
        echo $row1['vtname']; 
    }
}
```

With this query you will only get the data you actually want, so less data moved between database server and script, and less code to manipulate it